# Virtualbox not working with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, docker

I've been trying for a while to get VirtualBox working so I can use boot2docker on my Windows box at work.

In the log (called `VBoxHardening.log`) I frequently see `[lacks WinVerifyTrust]`

One in-context example:
`25dc.3450: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\privman64.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]`

This seems to be the main useful error message that I'm seeing.

Why am I getting these messages? Why might VirtualBox not be working for me?

VMware works fine, but I much prefer to get VirtualBox working. About one year ago I was always using VirtualBox with no problems.

Comment: [VirtualBox does not implement this function.  Verify you are using the current supported version of VirtualBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388208(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Does not implement which function?

Comment: `WinVerifyTrust`....I linked you to what it does, the log entry, indicates VirtualBox is loading a dll without calling that function.  The reason it "works" with VMWare is because VMWare does use that function.

Comment: Followed the link so I see what you mean. I am using Version 5.0.14 r105127. I don't know how to determine what the current supported version is. Do you mean the current stable version on the oracle site?

Comment: Current version is whatever is on the website

Comment: I am using the current version then. I think it has to do with the way my company's IT security is configured.

Comment: If you suspect that get an Administrator involved